# Why do I have different results in java and android projects .getBytes()

Tags: java, android

I made my own provider **stribog** (a hash function). Now I need to generate a key. I launch this code on 2 projects in Eclipse: one as a java project and one as an android project and it gives me 2 different results! How is it possible and why does it happen? I need to have the same result.

```
 byte [] secretByte = "3266341188".getBytes();
 MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("Stribog512");
 byte[] digest = md.digest(secretByte);
```

Comment: Maybe try a specific string encoding like UTF-8 and make sure that the hash function is correct.

Comment: First things first - check if you are getting consistent results with a Hash Provider that is well known like MD5 or SHA1. If that gives you consistent results - start debugging your implementation's digest method.

Comment: the problem was in encoding.... @GiantTree thanks!